# PySpark join two dataframes and update nested structure

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two Spark dataframes. I want to update the first one based on second.

df1

```
[
  {"sku": "abc-abc-abc", 
   "prod_id": "ss-23235", 
   "salePrice": "2312"
  }, {
   "sku": "xyz-xyz-xyz", 
   "prod_id": "ss-13265", 
   "salePrice": "8312"
  }
]
```

df2

```
[{
  "sku": "abc-abc-abc", 
  "min_price": "678"
 },{
  "sku": "xyz-xyz-xyz", 
  "min_price": "7655"
 }
]
```

I want to update the first dataframe (df1) as below

```
[
 {"sku": "abc-abc-abc", 
  "prod_id": "ss-23235", 
  "price": {
     "salePrice": "2312",
     "min_price": "678"
   },
 },
 {"sku": "xyz-xyz-xyz", 
  "prod_id": "ss-13265", 
  "price": {
     "salePrice": "8312",
      "min_price": "7655"
   }
 }
]
```

I'm not getting how to join the data inside nested structure

Comment: You can flatten the JSON and join. Please show us some attempts to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType, StructType, StructField
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

Source1 = [
  {"sku": "abc-abc-abc", 
   "prod_id": "ss-23235", 
   "salePrice": "2312"
  }, {
   "sku": "xyz-xyz-xyz", 
   "prod_id": "ss-13265", 
   "salePrice": "8312"
  }
]
Source2 = [{
  "sku": "abc-abc-abc", 
  "min_price": "678"
 },{
  "sku": "xyz-xyz-xyz", 
  "min_price": "7655"
 }
]

df1 = sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize(Source1))
df1.show()
df2 = sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize(Source2))
df2.show()
df3 = df1.join(df2,'sku',how='inner').select(df1.sku,df1.prod_id,df1.salePrice,df2.min_price).withColumn('price',F.to_json(F.struct(df1.salePrice,df2.min_price))).drop('salePrice').drop('min_price')
df4 = df3.select('sku','prod_id','price').withColumn('Output',F.to_json(F.struct('sku','prod_id','price'))).drop('sku').drop('prod_id').drop('price').show(truncate=False)
```

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Output                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"sku":"abc-abc-abc","prod_id":"ss-23235","price":"{"salePrice":"2312","min_price":"678"}"} |
|{"sku":"xyz-xyz-xyz","prod_id":"ss-13265","price":"{"salePrice":"8312","min_price":"7655"}"}|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Comment: while it might solve the problem, please give some explanation to your code

Comment: Hi pltc, I have joined the dataframes based on the key column and converted the required values to json string in df3 from both the source df's and then I have converted the all the values to json string in DF4